# How to perform the same query result as the actual stats

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have designed a cricket tournament database where I have gathered all of the real-time data and try to perform the following query.

I am trying to perform a query that will show the exact same results as on the actual stats from the official website as shown on the images.

**What I want to achieve** - I want the query to show the most runs scored in one innings made throughout the whole tournament exactly as shown like this. Please see https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/batting/most_runs_innings.html?id=13202;type=tournament

**Problem** - There are some players who have scored the most runs in the tournament more than once, however, due to my query, it will only show the player once. For example, M Labuschagne and D Warner appears more than once. This is because I am using **GROUP BY** player's names but I am not sure how to amend the query in order to make the names show more than once. Please see image attached.

[Most runs made in one innings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfx1W.png)

Code used:

```
SELECT p.name, innings, MAX(runs) AS max_runs
FROM testruns
JOIN players AS p
ON testruns.player_id = p.id
WHERE runs IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.name, innings
ORDER BY max_runs DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Tables created: matches, umpires, wickets, players, roles, venues, teams, testruns

[My testruns table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xazmV.png)

I am very new to SQL.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by p.name, innings` is making the rows unique by `p.name` and what I assume is the number of `innings` the player played in any particular game (please forgive my ignorance as we don't know cricket in the US).

Since the site you listed includes information about the match, that tells me that you should use `group by <matchid>, p.name, innings`, instead.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you so much for your reply. I can confirm, I have resolved it. I basically had to GROUP BY the match_id as well, so that it gives you all the maximum runs made in each match.